# Creative SDK support in production mode

Tags: adobecreativesdk

In one of the articles, its mentioned that the Creative SDK support only 25 users in the development mode.

May I know, how many users it supports in Production mode.

Supported platforms are: Mobile Web, iOS & Android

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for number of users of an app with a Creative SDK production ID.

[Instructions for getting your production ID are here](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204601215-How-to-complete-the-Production-Client-ID-Request). You will be asked for basic app details and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. We have a concern here with the SDK. We want to support the basic image editing features like crop, rotate, flip & enhance. The android APK file size is coming up around 15 MB after build, which is very big. Can you please let me know any alternative approach to reduce the size of the APK  to 4-5 MB max?

Comment: On Stackoverflow, it's better to open a new question for a new subject. As a quick answer, one good course of action, not limited to just the Creative SDK, is to [split the APK into CPU architectures and do multiple APK releases](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html). You may see bigger savings with this approach.